# Relative path for external graphic with parameters

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm having a problem constructing the links for my external graphics. In my xml for example I have this path: `/images/1.png`.

Now I want to print all the images from the xml in a `for-each`. But I don't know how to construct the following with a value from the current node:

```
url('resources/pdf/images/1.png')
```

The `resources/pdf` part is not in the xml.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your current content and xslt?

Comment: It looks like you need to use the `concat()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put 'resources/pdf' in a parameter (e.g. Path) and use the concat method:

```
  <fo:external-graphic  src="url({$Path}/{../../PublicationElement/Document/DocumentURL})" scaling="non-uniform"/>
```